# How are apps listed on the OSX "Apps using significant energy" list?

Tags: macos, webcam, osx-yosemite, energy

I created a small OSX app that takes a picture on the webcam every hour. However, as soon as the first webcam picture is taken, the app gets listed in the dreaded "Apps using significant energy" list under the MacBook battery menu. It then remains in this list until the app is closed.

[image]

However, when examined in Xcode, it is clear the app only consumes energy for the brief second that the photo is taken, as seen here:

[image]

Is there any way to tell OSX to re-audit energy usage? Or could I silently quit and restart my app after each photo to "clear its record"? How else can I get rid of this false bad-rap from the OS?

EDIT: Further research shows that simply accessing the camera is does *not* automatically put an app on this list. Apple's own Photo Booth app, for example, does not get listed even when it is filming video. I've edited the title and question to be more explicit about finding what it is that triggers this warning.

I'm using the popular [ImageSnap](https://github.com/samgreen/ImageSnapMavericks) code for taking the picture. The same issue happened with both the original and the new Mavericks-specific version.

Comment: Giving an answer to this would likely let others hijack this feature and abuse it. This almost seems like a better complaint to talk to Apple directly about. (Or something like that.)

Comment: @Blair I updated the question to clarify. I'm not looking for a way to trick the OS, but rather how to get OS to notice that my app is no longer using energy after the one photo. So if there is a solution, it shouldn't be something that can be abused. The fact that Photo Booth doesn't trigger the warning leads me to think that it may be something about the particular AVFoundation methods used to access the camera.

Comment: @Stan James, have you had answer for this question? I have a same problem. Please help.

Comment: @HuynhInc Sorry, still no solution. I thought the problem might have been the old way ImageSnap accessed the camera, and created a new fork that uses the latest AVFoundation methods. The code is better, but still triggers the energy warnings. :( https://github.com/wanderingstan/ImageSnapMavericks

Comment: @Stan James: OK. I understood. Thank you for your answer. If you have solution, please let me know. I'm very grateful for it.